# What should I do if an admissions office asks me for a bachelor's thesis, when my program didn't require it?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions

I recently applied to a university for a PhD program.They asked me to submit all of my documents.When I submitted my documents they asked for my Bachelors thesis. There is no Bachelors thesis or undergraduate research in our university.You can do it but its not a requirement and nobody does it given the time constraint of 6 months for Bachelors Final project. I have my Masters thesis but there was no bachelors thesis. There was a final project in bachelors but it was not research based. The hr said that "in case the thesis is not available,you can send an extended abstract". How do I properly address this situation ?

Comment: Send your master thesis?

Comment: Send the results of that final project?

Comment: Have you emailed/phoned them to ask them what to do/ what they actually want?

Comment: Send the one sentence "My university did not require a Bachelors thesis, so there is nothing for me to submit."

Comment: @Paxinum They are asking for both bachelors and Masters thesis.

Comment: @jojo I believe you already have the answer to your question: _send an extended abstract of your project_. You can also add a letter explaining the situation and stating that no Bachelor Thesis was required. You should send your Master Thesis as well.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in the comments above, I would send both the final project writeup and your masters thesis with a letter explaining the situation (no bachelors thesis required at your university), and contact the department and ask them how they wish you to proceed. At the end of the day, it's their requirement, so it's their call.

Comment: We were only required to submit the source code of the application and then give a viva of the project.No write up or document was required. What should I include in the bachelors write up ?

Comment: @jojo - Given that, I would definitely start with just calling the department and asking them what they want you to do.